# Refresh JSP after Servlet Changes in Database

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, refresh

I have a problem in my Java EE project about refreshing of jsp pages.
Every time a Servlet modifies the database in my project the changes do not appear in jsp pages. They appear only after the logout of the user.

Is there a method to make a refresh of the session after changes in the database MySQL?
(I use the server JBoss).

Comment: If I were you, I would check to see if the values read out of the database were being cached somehow. If so, you need to find some way to invalidate the cache when needed. Or you can do away with the cache and have the database values re-read everytime there is a page requested.

Comment: Are the values stored in session? Could you provide a piece of code to understand what you are doing?

Comment: Check caching at all levels.

Comment: I can modify values such as Name or Surname during the Change of the Profile but there is not a function that refreshes my session and allow me to see changes immediately. The code is exact but I want to refresh my jsp pages.@Nebelmann
What do you intend for checking cache?? @DaveNewton

Comment: If you're updating in the DB that is also stored in the session then you need to modify your code to actually do the right thing. Caching can affect your app at multiple levels, generally page and DB layers.

Comment: Ok and there is a method to refresh all levels immediately after the change? @DaveNewton

Comment: ... *You* have to update the object in session if it's a separate entity from the object you're using to update the DB. Web browser cache control is easily searchable. Your DB layer's caching should handle updates correctly, but there's no mention of any caching, ORM, etc. so it's impossible to provide useful input regarding that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the from the DB retrieved data in the session scope. Store it in the request scope. This way the enduser will get most recent data on every HTTP request.

If you worry about performance, then look for another solution than abusing the HTTP session as some kind of an inefficient and unmanagable cache. For example, a DB connection pool in order to connect with the DB in 1ms instead of 200~500ms, or a Java based 2nd level DB cache such as Terracotta and Ehcache in order to have a sane and managable shared cache instead of inefficiently duplicating the very same data for all users in different HTTP sessions as you're doing now.

This all is easier if you're using JPA instead of "plain old" JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:
when I set new parameters for my Profile I make a new `request.getSession.setAttribute(user);` before making the `getRequestDispatcher(myPage.jsp);`. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score -1):

- I have deleted the data base entry that needs to be updated
- I copied all fields of the the data bases entry
- I added the data point of the field that should be updated
- I added the new data base entry